# Wordpress custom post template is not valid

Tags: wordpress, templates, taxonomy

I created a custom type name 'feed', then create some template files as `single-feed.php`, `feed.php`, `taxonomy.php` and `archive-feed.php` but all of them don't work.
I get error "`ERROR: This is not a valid feed template.`"
Here is my code

```
  add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
  function create_posttype() {
     register_post_type( 'feed',
     array(
         'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Feed' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Feed' ),   
         'not_found' =>  __('No feed found'),
         'not_found_in_trash' => __('No feed found in Trash')
         ),
         'public' => true,
         'has_archive' => true,
         'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'feed','with_front'=>FALSE),
         'supports' => array('title','author', 'editor')
       )
    );
     flush_rewrite_rules();
 }
 register_taxonomy("feedgroup", array("feed"),
 array("hierarchical"=> true, "label" => "Feed Group", "singular_label" => "Feed", "rewrite"=>    true,'query_var' => true,'taxonomies'=>array('post-tag','feedgroup'),'slug'=>'feed'));
```

Comment: With only writing this much code won't show anything.You need to add some data and retrieve them.These all data will going to be in feed.php and by putting condition you can go to on single-feed.php on click of single post.

Comment: has you done `flush_rewrite_rules` after creating the custom post type?

Comment: That error message comes from the [do_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_feed) function.  I suspect you have a clash between your post type name and the built in WordPress feeds (RSS etc).  What happens if you change the name (just to test)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feed` is a reserved name and **should not** be used by themes or plugins.

There is no work around to this problem. The only solution you have is to rename your custom post type to maybe `feeds`

You can get a list of reserved names [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms). *Just a note, although this is on the `register_taxonomy` page, this list applies side wide for any naming convension, not just taxonomies*